# Type Mismatch error when altering a google.visualization.DataTable() column value even after explicitly changing its data type

Tags: google-visualization

I have a datatable that's being returned by `google.visualization.data.group()`

```
var aggData = google.visualization.data.group(
        view,
        [0],
        aggColumns
);
```

I want to set several columns to be of type string with a tooltip role, and converting values in them to an html string

```
for (var col=2; col < aggData.getNumberOfColumns(); col = col + 2){
    aggData.setColumnProperties(col,{'type':'string', 'role':'tooltip', 'p':{'html':true}});
    //looking to see if the column type was actually changed
    console.log('Column '+col+' type: ' + aggData.getColumnProperty(col, 'type'))
    for (var row = 0; row < aggData.getNumberOfRows(); row = row + 1){
        aggData.setValue(row, col, getHTML(aggData.getValue(row, col)))
    }
}

function getHTML(count) {;
    return 'Projects Completed: <b>' + count + '</b>';
}
```

I checked the column data type in the log and it does return a `string` but when i set the value to a string it throws a type mismatch error.

```
Column 2 type: string
Uncaught Error: Type mismatch. Value Projects Completed: <b>2</b> does not match type number in column index 2
```

I also tried setting the column type using `setColumnProperty()` method but it's the same result. What am I missing?

================================================================================================

Below is a snippet of the larger script if needed

Sample input data looks like

```
"Oct 1, 2019, 12:00:00 AM",Team C,68
"Sep 23, 2019, 12:00:00 AM",Team C,68
"Nov 29, 2019, 12:00:00 AM",Team C,87
"Dec 31, 2019, 12:00:00 AM",Team C,62
 ....................................
"Nov 21, 2018, 12:00:00 AM",Team A,79
"Dec 29, 2018, 12:00:00 AM",Team A,58
"Nov 15, 2018, 12:00:00 AM",Team B,96
"Dec 29, 2018, 12:00:00 AM",Team B,77
```

The data is being read into a data table

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('datetime', 'Year');
data.addColumn('string', 'Team');
data.addColumn('number', 'Total Score');


var groupData = google.visualization.data.group(
    data,
    [
        {
            column: 0,
            modifier: getYear,
            type: 'number'
        },
        1
    ],
    [
        {
            column: 2,
            aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum,
            type: 'number'
        },
        {
            column: 2,
            aggregation: google.visualization.data.count,
            type: 'number',
            role: 'tooltip'
        }
    ]
);

// create data view from groupData
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(groupData);

// sum column array
var aggColumns = [];

// use year (column 0) as first view column
var viewColumns = [0];

// build calculated view & agg columns for each team
groupData.getDistinctValues(1).forEach(function (team, index) {
    // add a column to the view for each team
    viewColumns.push({
        calc: function (dt, row) {
            if (dt.getValue(row, 1) === team) {
                return dt.getValue(row, 2);
            }
            return null;
        },
        label: team,
        type: 'number'
    });

    viewColumns.push({
        calc: function (dt, row) {
            if (dt.getValue(row, 1) === team) {
                return dt.getValue(row, 3);
            }
            return null;
        },
        label: 'Number of Projects',
        type: 'number'
    });

    // add sum column for each team
    aggColumns.push({
        aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum,
        column: index*2 + 1,
        label: team,
        type: 'number'
    });

    aggColumns.push({
        aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum,
        column: index*2 + 2,
        type: 'number',
        role: 'tooltip',
    });
});

// set view columns
view.setColumns(viewColumns);
var aggData = google.visualization.data.group(
    view,
    [0],
    aggColumns
);
/*
The aggData looks like

"2,018",137,2,173,2,0,0 
"2,019",864,12,"1,028",12,610,12
 */

for (var col=2; col < aggData.getNumberOfColumns(); col = col + 2){
    aggData.setColumnProperties(col,{'type':'string', 'role':'tooltip', 'p':{'html':true}});
    console.log('Column '+col+' type: ' + aggData.getColumnProperty(col, 'type'))
    for (var row = 0; row < aggData.getNumberOfRows(); row = row + 1){
        aggData.setValue(row, col, getHTML(aggData.getValue(row, col)))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data table method `setColumnProperties` isn't doing what you expect.

it only sets the properties portion of the column --> `'p':{'html':true}`

so after your code runs, you end up with the following in your column properties.

```
'p': {'type':'string', 'role':'tooltip', 'p':{'html':true}}
```

and in fact, it is not possible to change a column's type,
once it has been created.

instead, you'll need to either use the `addColumn` or `insertColumn` method.

another option would be to use a data view.
then you could use a calculated column for the tooltip,
and exclude the original column you are trying to change,
using the `setColumns` method on the data view.

Comment: thanks a lot for that clarification.....that's interesting (a little misleading to a newbie), I assumed the ```type``` ```label``` ```role``` etc are all 'properties' of a column

Comment: there is a `setColumnLabel` method, but no `setColumnType` or `setColumnRole`...